Is a random intercept necessary for multivariate models?
I’m modeling height and weight as joint outcomes in a Bayesian multivariate model with brms, using mvbind(height, weight) ~ x. Since both responses are from the same subjects, is it necessary to add a random intercept (1 | subject) to account for repeated measures?
My data looks like this:
+-------+-------+-------+
|subject|weight |height |
+-------+-------+-------+
|S1     | 65    | 1.3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|S2     | 75    | 1.7   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|S3     | 80    | 1.8   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|...    | ...   | ...   |
+-------+-------+-------+


This is the very opposite of clear: if there is only one measurement per subject, then in what sense is this a "repeated measures" dataset??

@whuber I updated my post to clarify the structure fo my dataset. Thanks for the suggestion.

No this is not necessary, you might have a term (1 | subject) if you have multiple measurements / rows from the same individual. That might happen, for example, if you're modelling multiple noisy measurements, but probably not what you have here.
+-------+-------+-------+
|subject|weight |height |
+-------+-------+-------+
|S1     | 65    | 1.3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|S2     | 75    | 1.7   |
+-------+-------+-------+
|S2     | 75.4  | 1.8   |   # other measurement from same subject
+-------+-------+-------+
|...    | ...   | ...   |

